firebase 10.25 can not get google cpc conversion data
After iOS firebase is updated to 10.25, in_app_purchase has no advertising channel. Can not get conversion data in Google AD system anymore.
We had try almost all mthods:
Include ATT .
add ADSupport.Framework
pod 'FirebaseAnalytics'
 
FirebaseApp.configure()
 SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
                
Analytics.setUserProperty("true", forName: AnalyticsUserPropertyAllowAdPersonalizationSignals)
Analytics.setConsent([
    .analyticsStorage: .granted,
    .adStorage: .granted,
    .adUserData: .granted,
    .adPersonalization: .granted,
])
Analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)

Analytics.setUserID(AppInfo.getUserId())


How to fixed this issue,
